# limits equality

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, cauchy-principal-value

I'm wonderig if the next is true in general,

$\lim\limits_{x\to\ a} f(x)\pm\lim\limits_{y\to\ a} g(y)= \lim\limits_{x\to\ a}  f(x)\pm\ g(x).$

The question arises because of Cauchy's principal value, in which I have an integral say for example 
$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty} \sin(x) dx $ and taking the limits as $\int_{-a }^{0} \sin(x) dx +\int_{0 }^{b} \sin(x) dx $ a and b tend to infinity, they both diverge, but if you take $\lim\limits_{a\to\infty}\int_{-a}^{a} \sin(x) dx = 0 $ because sine is an odd function. wouldn't it be correct to just take the VP always instead of the other definition, I mean what's the point of separating the literals

thanks

Comment: The improper integral does not exist here because the integral $\int_{x=0}^{\infty} \sin(x)dx$ does not exist.

Comment: but if you get -cos(x) you evaluate the upper limit a and lower - a you obtain -cos(a)+cos(-a), because cos(x)=cos(-x) we have cos(a)-cos(a) which is 0, this i have without having to do the limit of the VP, but separately they dont cancel out so they diverge

Comment: Yes, and by definition, the improper integral does not exist because it is definded by the sum of the two integrals, which must both exist.